# How to add a Firestore batch write method to this Google Apps Script library

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore, shared-libraries, libraries

I want to write and send a pull request for a [Firestore batch write method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to the [FirestoreGoogleAppsScript library](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript/blob/master/Firestore.js). The only problem is, I have no idea how to do that. So I need help getting started. The above link is the file where I think I should add the following.

```js
/**
 * Create a batch write with the given fields and an auto-generated ID.
 *
 * @param {string} path the path where the document will be written
 * @param {object} fields the document's fields
 * @return {object} the Document object written to Firestore
 */
this.batch = function (path, fields) {
  const request = new FirestoreRequest_(baseUrl, authToken)
  return createDocument_(path, fields, request)
}
```

When finished, I would expect to call the function as follows.

```js
// Get a new write batch
let batch = db.batch();

// Set the value of 'NYC'
let nycRef = db.collection('cities').doc('NYC');
batch.set(nycRef, {name: 'New York City'});

// Update the population of 'SF'
let sfRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');
batch.update(sfRef, {population: 1000000});

// Delete the city 'LA'
let laRef = db.collection('cities').doc('LA');
batch.delete(laRef);

// Commit the batch
return batch.commit().then(function () {
  // ...
});
```

Is this the correct way to approach it or am I missing something?

Comment: Firestore API cannot be used by batch request. When I saw the source script of libraries for [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes), it seems that each command is requested every method. Official document says `Each operation in the batch counts separately towards your Cloud Firestore usage.`. From these situation, I think that it is required to call each command every method. By the way, can I ask you about the link which can see `this.batch = function (path, fields) {` in your script? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike: I don't see the `this.batch = function (path, fields) {` I'm wondering if that would be a way to add a new method to the library. Would adding that method to the existing library be a successful way to add batch writing functionality to the library? Or does much more need to be done?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From the official libraries, I thought that it is required to call each command every method. About this, if you want to achieve `Would adding that method to the existing library be a successful way to add batch writing functionality to the library?`, for example, how about sending pull request by modifying the script of the library? Or how about creating the batch method using the library? If these are not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @LetMeTinkAboutIt, I tink now is the best time for a pull request after the codebase redesign. I'm all ears if you need any guidance on [the issue](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript/issues/65)! :) Thanks!